# How to extract decimal number from input file?

Tags: java

i am new to Java and am currently stuck on some school work.
My program is reading from a input file with lines.
If my input file has a line like

"Orville's Acres, 114.8  43801"

I have to break the text, double, integer into separate parts.
I have the name part done but stuck on the numbers part.

how do i extract just 114.8 and then just 43801?
I need the numbers one at a time.
In the end I need to divide 114.8 into 43801. Then to the next line.

```
 Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(inFile);
 fileInput.useDelimiter( "\\D+" );
 double i=0;
 while ( fileInput.hasNextDouble() ){
 i=fileInput.nextDouble(); // get int
 System.out.println(i);
 }
```

I tried this but it prints out 
114.0
8.0
43801.0

As you can see, the decimal number is not correct and I need only one number at a time.

Comment: did you try lower-case `d`? (for digit) - as in `fileInput.useDelimiter("\\d+");`

Comment: Just tried, output was blank. Thank you for responding by the way.

Comment: if you have decimal points, try using `fileInput.hasNextFloat()` and `nextFloat()` instead of double

Answer (score 2):

Considering the input "114.8 43801", you would want to use a white space as your delimiter. By using '\D+' as your delimiter, your split the string at any non digit as per the Java documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Hence, you are splitting at the dot of '114.8'.

Try to use the default whitespace delimiter (Do no set one..) and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You should use regular expressions. [docs for Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

```
String raw="Orville's Acres, 114.8 43801";
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("\\d+.?[\\d]*");
Matcher m=p.matcher(raw);
while(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Output:

`114.8
43801`

Answer (score 0):

The reason you got 8 as a separate `token` was because you set the `delimiter` as '\D+' as Vincent noted. Think of `delimiter` as a rule you specify as for how to separate a line of String into different `tokens`, where a token is like a single piece.

Without specifying a delimiter you set above, i.e., with using the default delimiter, you will be separating String by white spaces such as `' ', '\t', '\n'`.
That means you will be able to get these tokens as String value by calling `scanner.getNext()`:

`{Orville's}, {Acres,}, {114.8}, {43801}`.

And if you have a knowledge of the format of your input data, you can use `Integer.parse(string)` `Double.parse(string)`. These will interpret the numbers in the String value and return it to you. However, note that if the string parameter you pass to those methods is not in a format the `parse()` methods expect (example: `string = "One"` or `string = myId123`, which includes stuff that is not a number), you would get a format exception and your programme will crash.

You said you've done the name part; I would assume that you were able to get the following `line` part. Assuming you have a knowledge of the format of your input data, you know that a double has a "." in the token. Thus you could try out the following codes:

```
String line = "114.8 43801";
while (scanner.hasNext())
{
    String token = scanner.next();

    if (token.contains("."))    // return true if the string has "." in it
    {
        doubleToken = Double.parseDouble(token);
        System.out.println(doubleToken);    // prints "114.8"
    }
    else
    {
        intToken = Integer.parseInt(token);
        System.out.println(intToken);       // prints "43801"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the format of the lines in the file is guaranteed to be:

```
String Double Integer
```

or when the name has two words in it:

```
String String Double Integer
```

you can split the individual lines into the three parts and parse from there. You currently seem to be focusing on getting individual parts out of the scanner at a time, when you can get an entire line to work with.

```
Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(inFile);
String name = "";
double d = 0;
int i = 0;

while (fileInput.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = fileInput.nextLine(); // get the entire line
    String[] parts = line.split(" ");   // split into its three parts

    if (parts.length == 3) {
        name = parts[0];                    // the first part is the name
        d = Double.valueOf(parts[1]);       // the second part is the double
        i = Integer.valueOf(parts[2]);      // the third part is the integer
    } else {
        name = parts[0] + " " + parts[1];   // the name is the first two parts
        d = Double.valueOf(parts[2]);       // the third part is the double
        i = Integer.valueOf(parts[3]);      // the fourth part is the integer
    }
    System.out.println("Got name: " + name + ", double: " + d + ", int: " + i);
}
```

This is a very limited example, but based on the sample input, it will work. It can be extended to work with lines whose names have any number of words if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way you can go is:
1) Read entire line as a String using BufferedReader
2) split the string using 'space' as a delimiter and it will return String[] array
3) for(each element in array)
   3.1) print ( Double.parseDouble(element) )

Answer (score 0):

you only change your regex to

`\\d+.?[\\d]*`